# Reverse Engineering on Liquibase

Tags: mysql, sql, database, liquibase

Right now i am working on Spring Boot with Liquibase , Liquibase is creating tables properly but the  thing i need to know is , can we do Reverse Engineering ?
I want to create Liquibase Scripts on the basis of MySql Database, is it possible ?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html

Comment: @Mureinik thank you , that really helped :)